# Lightning Design System SVG Path Issues

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, svg-icon

I am trying to display an icon in a lightning component using LDS. I setup the svg helper, component, and renderer as per the LDS docs [here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/resources/lightning-svg-icon-component-helper/). I also have a static resource stored in SalesForce. I am trying to reference it like this:

```
<c:svgIcon svgPath="/resource/sldsRight.png" category="standard" size="small" />
```

However, the icon does not appear. Is my path wrong, or do I have the wrong file type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for icons I would recommend using standard salesforce provided components instead:

```
<lightning:icon iconName="utility:right"/>
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_icon.htm

linked to the icons in that doc -

https://lightningdesignsystem.com/icons/

Answer (score 0):

The svgIcon component is meant for SVG files, not JPG, PNG, GIF, or BMP resources. In Lightning, you still normally use `<img>` tags to display images. Please note that the resource name is incorrect; you normally just refer to it by its defined name, such as `/resource/sldsRight`. If you're using the icon zip file, you'd then refer the full path and extension, such as `/resource/sldsicons/utility/right_60.png` instead.